# Live preview button(s) gone after enabling different domain for control panel

Tags: control-panel, craft4, multi-domain, headers

I'm building a Craft website which will need another domain for the control panel.
The setup for this has gone good using this article. => https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/access-control-panel-from-alternate-domain

However I'm now faced with some issues related to this setup.

- The live preview buttons are gone when editing entries
- The craft icon font was being blocked by CORS

I have found 2 articles which seemed interesting:

- https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/live-preview-alternate-control-panel-domain
- https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/using-live-preview-across-multiple-subdomains

Based on these articles I added the following Headers to the .htaccess file

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' 'my-website.com' 'cms.website.com';"
```

This fixed the issue with the font but it did not bring back the live preview button(s).
What am I doing wrong?